# Windows 8 on network and self-assigned IPs

Tags: networking, windows-8, router, ethernet, switch

Whenever I turn off my computer, my friend's computer (who is on the same network) loses Internet access and grabs a self-assigned IP, and the router stops reporting any computers connected to the network.

I have a Windows 8 custom built PC on my home network. An ethernet cable from my router runs to a switch which provides Internet access to my computer and my roommate's computer, an IBM ThinkCentre.

WiFi still works on my GS3 and his iPod though, as well as our two Xboxes.

This is a consistent problem.

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you fix it (temporarily) by giving your friends machine a static IP address?

Comment: I can, yes, however I would like, and really need, a more permament solution to the problem, as I have several devices that come on and off the network and I don't have the time to go through and program each one, plus each new device, to a static IP address.

Comment: Sounds like quite the issue! In this scenario, one of the most helpful things I can think of is doing a packet capture on the machines while recreating the issue. It sounds like a DHCP Release issue, and a capture (using Wireshark) could provide lots of insight.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea how to use WireShark. Tried before, but I was so lost.

Comment: You might be running a DHCP server on your PC. Have you ever used the Windows function to share the Internet connection?

Comment: Nope. Can't, my computer doesn't have the hardware to.